# How to check Intel iGPU frequency on Linux?

Tags: kernel, intel-graphics

I own Intel Haswell G3420. At stock its iGPU has 1,15 GHz turbo frequency. In my UEFI I overclocked the iGPU to 1,5 GHz and added voltage. However the framerates in both benchmarks and games are the same after the OC. I once read that Intel iGPU OC doesn't work on Linux because of some problems with turbo boost in Linux kernel. I want to check if the frequency while gaming hits 1,5 Ghz or if it stays unchanged at 1,15 GHz. So I need a way to check current Intel iGPU frequency. I know that Nvidia binary drivers are capable of that, however I have no idea how can I check it using Intel iGPU.

TL;DR

How can I check Intel iGPU current frequency on Linux?

Answer (score 0):

### Option #1

```
sudo apt install intel-gpu-tools
sudo intel_gpu_frequency
```

### Option #2

```
sudo find /sys -type f -name gt_cur* -print0 | xargs -0 cat
```

Comment: Can you explain how these command lines works?

Answer (score 0):

Conky constantly updates iGPU speed for me:

[image: intel gpu temp.gif]

In this image I'm stressing GPU with graphics test and the conky displays results on desktop. Unfortunately `glxgears` barely stress iGPU which stays at minimum frequency.

The relevant `conky` code:

```
#------------+
# Intel iGPU |
#------------+
${color orange}${hr 1}${if_match "intel" == "${execpi 99999 prime-select query}"}
${color2}${voffset 5}Intel® Skylake GT2 HD 530 iGPU @${alignr}${color green}${execpi .001 (cat /sys/class/drm/card1/gt_cur_freq_mhz)} MHz
${color}${goto 13}Min. Freq:${goto 120}${color green}${execpi .001 (cat /sys/class/drm/card1/gt_min_freq_mhz)} MHz${color}${goto 210}Max. Freq:${alignr}${color green}${execpi .001 (cat /sys/class/drm/card1/gt_max_freq_mhz)} MHz
${color orange}${hr 1}${else}
#------------+
# Nvidia GPU |
#------------+
${color2}${voffset 5}${execpi .001 (nvidia-smi --query-gpu=gpu_name --format=csv,noheader)} ${color1}@ ${color green}${execpi .001 (nvidia-smi --query-gpu=clocks.sm --format=csv,noheader)} ${alignr}${color1}Temp: ${color green}${execpi .001 (nvidia-smi --query-gpu=temperature.gpu --format=csv,noheader)}°C
${color1}${voffset 5}Ver: ${color green}${execpi .001 (nvidia-smi --query-gpu=driver_version --format=csv,noheader)} ${color1} P-State: ${color green}${execpi .001 (nvidia-smi --query-gpu=pstate --format=csv,noheader)} ${alignr}${color1}BIOS: ${color green}${execpi .001 (nvidia-smi --query-gpu=vbios_version --format=csv,noheader)}
${color1}${voffset 5}GPU:${color green}${execpi .001 (nvidia-smi --query-gpu=utilization.gpu --format=csv,noheader)} ${color1}Ram:${color green}${execpi .001 (nvidia-smi --query-gpu=utilization.memory --format=csv,noheader)} ${color1}Pwr:${color green}${execpi .001 (nvidia-smi --query-gpu=power.draw --format=csv,noheader)} ${alignr}${color1}Freq: ${color green}${execpi .001 (nvidia-smi --query-gpu=clocks.mem --format=csv,noheader)}
${color orange}${hr 1}${endif}
```

To make a long story short:

```
cat /sys/class/drm/card*/gt_cur_freq_mhz
```

Will give you your current iGPU frequency.

Answer (score -2):

```
cat  /sys/kernel/debug/dri/0/i915_cur_delayinfo
```

CAGF will give the the current fz to 100Mhz resolution.

Comment: Can you explain how this works.

Comment: "Permission denied" without `sudo`, "No such file or directory" with it.